# VBA ("Scripting.Dictionary").Exists returns false when it is supossed to be true

Tags: vba, dictionary

I'm trying to count the letter `P`. The code I have right now "breaks" in the `if` statement because `resDict.Exist` is `false`, We know this because `if` the statement is changed to a `If Not` it executes the body of the `if`.

It always goes directly to the end of the `if`. I got the reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" selected so that shouldn't be the problem.

```
' Get results from 'resDict' dictionary
Function CountResult(word As String) As Integer
    Set resDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    If resDict.Exists(UCase(word)) Then
        count = resDict.Item(UCase(word))
    End If

    CountResult = count
End Function
```

*Edit:*
I just found out that in a previous piece of code the dictionary is getting filled.
Now what i am tryingo do is make the dicitionary  public so that it can be used in the piece of code i have posted before the edit. Are there anytips on how to do so since i keep getting the error `Compilingerror: invalid Charactesteric in sub or function` for this piece of code:

```
Sub CountResults()
    Public resDict
    Set resDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
```

Comment: How is anything getting added to `resDict`?

Comment: A bit more detailed: This line `Set resDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` creates a new empty dictionary `resDict` and since you never fill the dictionary with any data, there is no data that exists. Therefore `.Exists` always returns `False`.

Comment: @peh thank you, how can we fill the dictionary?

Comment: @Brynn Read about the object :o)

Comment: resDict.add 'key' , 'content' or resDict.item('key') = 'content'

Comment: If you want to count the occurrences of one letter in a word, I think there might be easier ways to do so without using a dictionary.

Comment: I think @VincentG is correct and you are asking a [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] your question and tell a bit more detailed what you are actually trying to archive. So probably we are able to suggest a better way.

Comment: I can and will try to expand the question the thing is i am currently debugging this code since it stopped working and my guess is that this is the final bug i have to fix before the code works again

Comment: @VincentG i am trying to count the letter P in the 3th row of a table. The only part that doesnt work is the counting part and that it "Breaks" because it skips the body of the if loop

Comment: @Brynn have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ. Hi i was rethinking this whole question and i think what i am trying to do is add items to the dictionary. But i think i might be lacking the information about what i need to add. Therefore i am rethinking if t is a good idea to try and bug fix this error or to rewrite the whole method. Do you perhaps have an idea about how to add stuff to the dictionary?

Comment: As a comment i would liek to add to my last comment,
The resDict Dictionary is indeed getting stuff from another sub, I know this thanks to this comment `' Count test results and store them in the 'resDict' dictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution i was searching for turned out to be a public variable.
To do so i needed to add as the first line of the code (outside every sub and function) this line of code

```
Public resDict As Variant
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to count the occurrences of a letter in a string you can use something like this:

```
Function CountOccurrencesOf(Letter As String, InString As String, Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As Long
    CountOccurrencesOf = Len(InString) - Len(Replace$(InString, Letter, vbNullString, , , IIf(CaseSensitive, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)))
End Function
```

And call the function like:

```
MsgBox CountOccurrencesOf(Letter:="A", InString:="A Sentence with occurences of a or A or anything else", CaseSensitive:=False)
```

---

As Nathan_Sav pointed out: For multiple letter counting (eg `Letter:="en"`) you would need to devide by `Len(Letter)`:

```
CountOccurrencesOf = (Len(InString) - Len(Replace$(InString, Letter, vbNullString, , , IIf(CaseSensitive, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)))) / Len(Letter)
```

Comment: Also, i use this a lot.  I use what @Peh has put, but i also add `/len(letter)` then this translates to use for multiple char length searches.  Or losing the case sensitivity, you can also use `count_occurances = UBound(Split(strIn, strLookFor))`